# Overlay in webview app

Tags: android, webview

I am building a webview app for discuss.flarum.org, an open source project. Everything goes fine with the app other than when I tried to use the website's ( forum's ) editor, it gives an overlay. I am attaching both overlay as in app and original editor view as in mobile browser. Please help me fix the overlay.

[image: Overlay in Editor of webview app]

[image: Editor view as in mobile browser]

PS : I used this guide to build the webview app

http://www.coderefer.com/create-android-app-for-website/

Comment: Can you provide a test repo link? So I can debug it.

Comment: @JohnWatsonDev , sure. Give me 5 mins

Comment: @JohnWatsonDev I have created a test repo here : https://github.com/meetdilip/myApp

Comment: OK, I will check it.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWatsonDev

Comment: Please imports your repo and checks it again. It's broken.

Comment: Shall I upload my file in Google Drive. I am not very familiar with Github

Comment: OK. I will get it.

Comment: @JohnWatsonDev  Uploaded my Android Studio folder into Google Drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4j3jK5pIcBINTMzUmMxTUVrNzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please expand on the detail of your bug. What do you want? The Pictures on the post hesitated me.

Comment: The app lets me view the website ( forum ) without any glitch. But, when I try to post something using the " reply " option available on the website, it gives me an overlay as in pic 1. There is no issue in mobile browser though ( pic 2 ). I am trying to get rid of that overlay and make app give the option as in pic 2. Kindly let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: Emm. I got what you want. Let me check it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWatsonDev

Comment: @JohnWatsonDev , any update ?